# Laravel form validation, why I don't have the $errors variable available on my view?

Tags: php, validation, laravel, view

Taken from lrvl 5.1 documentation, I read:
using these lines in the controller:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
    'author.name' => 'required',
    'author.description' => 'required',
]);
```

If validation doesn't pass controller stops execution and redirect back to previous location.

This is happening correctly.

Then doc says:
"$errors variable will always be available in all of your views on every request"

And then suggests the following blade code:

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
@endif
```

But actually I'll get a ErrorException undefined variable errors....

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure your code using web middleware.

Comment: Show your controller and view source code.

Comment: This could happen if you using `laravel` 5.2 without web middleware, cause errors variable stores in session which bootstrap in web middleware

Comment: using web middlware now. Work like charme. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer myself to this question, 
just in case It was not clear the commented solution.
(Thanks to train_fox for the hint).

Just add 'web' middleware usage.
in your routing that is target in form action (get/post)

Example:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'],       
       function(){
          Route::post('/edit'           , 'My_Controller@edit');
       });
```

Variable $errors the becomes available on view to be parsed.